# Non-member operator as private member of foreign class

Tags: c++, class, operator-keyword, member, non-static

Is it possible to have a non-member operator like

```
bool operator==(const std::string &l, const Token r)
```

as a private member function of an unrelated class `Interpreter`?
I tried it the obvious way, but it doesn't work (too many arguments).
I know, already the title "non-member function [...] as member" says the opposite, but is there a better way than a function

```
bool isToken(const std::string &l, const Token r)
```

to make a comparison which is dependant on a (non-static) member of `Interpreter`?

It isn't possible to compare `Token`s to `string`s outside of an `Interpreter`.

Some further information: Token is an enum and the comparisation is dependant on the language set on construction of an `Interpreter`.

Comment: What is a `Token`, and how would `==` work if `Token` was the LHS?

Comment: Token is an enum like KEYWORD_ELSE or CONDITION_ALWAYS.
KEYWORD_ELSE == "else" should be true for an "english" Interpreter and KEYWORD_ELSE == "sonst" should be true for a "german" Interpreter.

Comment: Also, how did you imagine the syntax to look like if the == operator was defined inside Intepreter? Or you are asking for an operator that would just work in the context of Interpreter, i.e. for member methods of Interpreter?

Comment: Rather than comparing token to string, could you perhaps convert the string to a token (within the context of an Interpreter) and then compare the resulting tokens to each other?

Comment: Does your program require dynamic binding to interpreters, or can you assume your program operates in a single language mode for its duration?

Comment: How should I implicitly convert a string to a token just within the context of Interpreter? I could add a converting constructor Token(string s) to Token, but that would also have no access to the Interpreter. It should be possible to open multiple tabs in the Editor with different languages set, so making interpreter a singleton or the translation static isn't possible here.

Comment: @Fabian: at least from what you've said, it sounds to me like a Token should have a ctor that accepts a string and an Interpreter as input. The Token is then created from the string using the Interpreter.

Comment: Which means I'd have to change Token into a constructable type and I'd still have to write `Token{"else", *this} == KEYWORD_ELSE`.
That's even longer than my `matches("else", KEYWORD_ELSE)` I have right now. So it's not possible to just write `"else" == KEYWORD_ELSE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to make a version of `operator ==` the way you want. It can't be made static. If it is a member, then it must take one argument.

If you are willing to "duplicate code", then you can play tricks with namespaces. Your generic interpreter could be a template that takes a language specific derived class as a template parameter. It in turn calls a templated `operator==` based on a language specific token.

```
template <typename TOKEN>
bool operator == (const std::string &l, const TOKEN token) {
    return token == l;
}

// Language specific interpreters inherit from this template
template <typename LANG>
class Interpreter {
public:
    void interpret () {
        std::string s("hi");
        if (s == LANG::KEYWORD_ELSE) {}
    }
};
```

Each language specific subclass of `Interpreter` lies in a language specific namespace. The implementation repeats enumerations of the  keywords, but otherwise defers to the template implementation.

```
namespace Lang0 {
    class Interpreter : public ::Interpreter<Lang0::Interpreter> {
        //...
    public:
        enum Token { KEYWORD_ELSE, //...
                   };
        static Interpreter & instance () {
            static Interpreter interpreter;
            return interpreter;
        }
    };
}

namespace Lang1 {
    class Interpreter : public ::Interpreter<Lang1::Interpreter> {
        //...
    public:
        enum Token { KEYWORD_ELSE, //...
                   };
        static Interpreter & instance () {
            static Interpreter interpreter;
            return interpreter;
        }
    };
}
```

Each namespace also provides a language specific implementation for `operator==` to compare a string to the language specific token.

```
namespace Lang0 {
    bool operator == (const Interpreter::Token token, const std::string &l) {
        //...
    }
}

namespace Lang1 {
    bool operator == (const Interpreter::Token token, const std::string &l) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Then, when the template implementation of `Interpreter` calls the template version of `operator==`, it resolves to the language specific implementation in the respective language specific namespace.

Comment: Code duplication wouldn't work either, sadly.
Interpreter loads a given database with the translations into a map.
Is there a reason why C++ doesn't allow this or has it been forgotten/wasn't intended?

Comment: I am not sure how to answer your question. I was under the impression, since you wanted to place the `operator==` as a member of `Interpreter`, that the comparisons would only happen in the context of an `Interpreter` instance. That's why I thought the above solution would work out for you. I had assumed the English Interpreter would be a different instance than the Deutsch Intepreter.

Comment: The languages supported aren't known at compile-time.
I'll likely let the user define custom languages and let him select it for his programs. Something like `Interpreter tab1('user1.lang');`

Comment: My solution will still work. Instead based on languages, the namespaces could name language indexes (`Lang0` and `Lang1`). This works so long as you are willing to limit the number of languages you can support.

Comment: No, this is more complicated and more a useless hack with limitations than a better way to "match(token,string)".

Comment: You asked if there was a way in C++, which is what I have shown. If it were for myself with your requirements, I would probably use an embedded scripting language to do the interpreting.

Answer (score 0):

Since comparison is made by a non-static member of Interpreter (say, is_equal()), you need three objects to make a comparison: an Interpreter, a string, and a Token.

If you know there is exactly one valid Interpreter object instance at the time of comparison, you could have this instance made accessible statically, e.g.

```
bool operator==(const std::string &l, const Token r)
{
   return Interpreter::instance().is_equal(l, r);
}
```

where static member instance() returns the Interpreter object that does the work.